# How to score the predictions of a classification model?

Tags: classification, svm, z-score

I have made a classification model using support vector machine for the classification of two classes.The model is giving probability score and decision value for the test and training set and also for the input prediction. How to use these values to give a generalized score for the new input that has to be classified in one of two classes?

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity: Are you sure that your model gives you probability scores? For Naive Bayes that would definitively make sense, but in the context of SVM's i'm not sure if this is correct...

Comment: @NeuroMorphing It possibly uses Platt's method (or some similar technique) to generate probabilities from the SVM output (essentially fitting a regularised univariate logistic regression to the output).  Personally if you want probabilities from a kernel model, I'd use Gaussian Process Classification or Kernel Logistic Regression.

Answer (score -1):

To score the predictions of a classification model, first use argmax function on your probability scores to first convert them into class labels and then use evaluation metrics precision scores, recall scores, confusion matrix depending upon the problem statement.

Comment: Cross Validated advocates for direct assessment of the probabilities using strictly proper scoring rules like a tier score and log loss, as (among other reasons) this eliminates arbitrary thresholding.

Comment: Very true but don't forget a rich history of probability accuracy scoring rules, starting with the Brier score.

Comment: @Dave I don’t think it is valid to say that Cross Validated “advocates” anything.